# Defining Private Route in react redux application?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to define PrivateRoute functional component to use in routes file. Routes is defined in routes.js file as shown below.

```
 const routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    element: <DashboardLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'account', element: <AccountView /> },
      { path: 'customers', element: <CustomerListView /> },

      { path: 'dashboard', element: <DashboardView /> },
      { path: 'services', element: <AddServiceView /> },
      { path: 'recommendation-details/:accountId/:recommendationId/:category', element: <Recommendation /> },

      { path: 'products', element: <ProductListView /> },
      { path: 'settings', element: <SettingsView /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', element: <LoginView /> },
      { path: 'register', element: <RegisterView /> },
      { path: '404', element: <NotFoundView /> },
      { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/login" /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
    ]
  }
];
```

So just help me in managing private routes in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I am using so this is simpler then the above method. No need write private route component. This worked for me. In App.js

```
    const App = () => {  
  useEffect(() => {
   store.dispatch(loadUser())
  }, [])
  const {isAuthenticated} = useSelector(state => state.auth)
  const routing = useRoutes(routes(isAuthenticated));
  return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        {routing}
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

In routes.js

```
    const routes = (isAuthenticated)=>[
  {
    path: 'app',
    element:isAuthenticated? <DashboardLayout />:<Navigate to="/login"/>,
    children: [
      { path: 'account', element:<AccountView /> },
      { path: 'customers', element: <CustomerListView /> },
      
      { path: 'dashboard', element:isAuthenticated?<DashboardView />:<Navigate to="/login"/> },
      { path: 'services', element: <AddServiceView /> },
      { path: 'recommendation-details/:accountId/:recommendationId/:category', element: <Recommendation />},

      { path: 'products', element: <ProductListView /> },
      { path: 'settings', element: <SettingsView /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: !isAuthenticated?<MainLayout />:<Navigate to="app/dashboard"/>,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', element: <LoginView /> },
      { path: 'register', element: <RegisterView /> },
      { path: '404', element: <NotFoundView /> },
      { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/login" /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
    ]
  }
];

export default routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a component called PrivateRouting like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { paths } from '@/constans/Paths';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={paths.home} />
    )} />
  );
};
export default PrivateRoute;

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired
};
```

usage of this component is simple

just like this

```
function RouterComponent() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Router>
      <divclassName="container-fluid">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={paths.home}>
            <Home setAuthentication={setIsAuthenticated}></Home>
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path={paths.gaming}
            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
            component={Gaming} />
          <PrivateRoute path={paths.score}
            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
            component={ScoreBoard} />
          <Route component={Error} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

You are just passing isAuthenticated props true if not it will redirect you to /home.

In your case you can path:"abc" element:PrivateRoute path="abc" isAuthenticated />

Comment: You are correct this does not work in my case as I am using useroutes() for routing. I have found the solution and sharing.